# Pandas create column counter that resets when the length exceeds a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
       A      B  
0   john    doe   
1  jacob  smith 
2   juli  patel  
3  jason bourne
4  alan  turing
```

I want to create a new column C where it is the concatenation of columns A and B and a counter starting from 1. However, if the total length of A+B+Counter exceeds 11, then I want to reset the counter back to 1.

So for the above dataframe, the column C would be:

```
       A      B    C
0   john    doe   johndoe1
1  jacob  smith   jacobsmith2
2   juli  patel   julipatel3
3  jason bourne   jasonbourne1
4  alan  turing   alanturing2
```

Comment: From your second, it has already exceeded 11 right?

Comment: If you're talking about "jacobsmith2", it's length is 11, so it wouldn't violate the condition. "jasonbourne1" violates it since adding the counter makes its length 12, so instead it doesn't become "jasonbourne4".

Comment: so the length of the counter itself is 1 regardless of the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "A": ["john", "jacob", "juli", "jason", "alan"],
    "B": ["doe", "smith", "patel", "bourne", "turing"],
}

counter = 0


def update_trans(row):
    global counter
    length = len(row["A"] + row["B"])
    if length >= 11:
        counter = 1
    else:
        counter += 1
    return f"{row['A']}{row['B']}{str(counter)}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df["C"] = df.apply(update_trans, axis=1)
    print(df.head())
```

See if this helps...

Since this task seemed basic, leveraging [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function might be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
s = df['A'] + df['B']
s + df.groupby((s.str.len()).ge(11).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```